# Puppeteer serving different pages for the same URL Headless vs Headful

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, dom, puppeteer

I'm not exactly sure why this happens but, I'm trying to scrape the results from Google search results and the results are dynamically loaded as you scroll down. I'm trying to simulate that by scrolling down however when puppeteer is running in headless mode, it doesn't load all the search results whereas when headless is turned off, it returns the correct number of results.

I found that the information I'm looking for is stored in divs with class 'bkWMgd' as you can see there are 7 divs in total:

[image]

Puppeteer code:

```js
(async (searchQuery) => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        //headless: false
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto('https://google.com/search?q='+searchQuery, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });

    //Wait for one of the div classes to load
    await page.waitForSelector('div[class=bkWMgd]');


    //Scroll all the way down
    await page.evaluate(() => window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight));

    //Counts how many div with class 'bkWMgd' there are
    const resp = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelectorAll('div[class=bkWMgd]').length);

    console.log(resp);

    await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});

    await browser.close();

})('cats')
```

Running this code in headless mode console.logs `3` and running it with headless mode turned off outputs the correct number `7`

These are the screenshots that are captured:

Headless Mode:
[image]

Headless Mode OFF: 
[image]

For some reason, It seems that different results are being outputted.  I tried creating an IngocnitoContext:

```js
    const context = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();

    const page = await context.newPage();
```

However, it still leads to different results, therefore I was just wondering if there was a way to ensure that both headless and headful produce the same results. The results I'm interested in are the ones that being produced by when headless is turned off

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google (and other websites) may serve you different content depending on your user agent and your screen size. Try explicitly setting them so that you get consistent results:

**Setting Window Size**

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    args: [
      '--window-size=1920,1080',
      '--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"'
    ]
});
```

**Setting User Agent**

```js
await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36');
```

**Full Example**

```js
(async (searchQuery) => {
    const userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36';
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: true,
      args: [
        '--window-size=1920,1080',
        `--user-agent="{userAgent}"`
      ]
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.setUserAgent(userAgent);

    await page.goto('https://google.com/search?q='+searchQuery, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });

    //Wait for one of the div classes to load
    await page.waitForSelector('div[class=bkWMgd]');


    //Scroll all the way down
    await page.evaluate(() => window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight));

    //Counts how many div with class 'bkWMgd' there are
    const resp = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelectorAll('div[class=bkWMgd]').length);

    console.log(resp);

    await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});

    await browser.close();

})('cats')
```

**Update**

I'm surprised that setting the user agent didn't work. I've updated my example to specify the user agent via the `--user-agent` command line switch. Couldn't hurt to try that.

There's a library called [Puppeteer Stealth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth) that will likely solve your issues. You might want to give that a try.

Comment: Unfortunately, trying this doesn't work. It seems that Google might be observing the User-Agent of the Browser? After printing out the Browser's User Agent the only difference is that instead of "Chrome" you have "HeadlessChrome". Regardless of whether or not we set the User-Agent for the page, the browser's User Agent stays the same and only changes with headless being set during launch. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Hi @WaqasAbbasi. I really thought setting the user agent would do the trick. Maybe give puppeteer stealth a try.

Comment: I tried --user-agent and unfortunately that doesn't work either, however Puppeteer Stealth works great!